# Pass Devexpress grid control values to texbox

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

How can I pass the selected row column values in gridview to texbox using Devexpress Gridcontrol?

Answer (score 0):

click on `gridView` under the `GridControl` then go on Events find `FocusedRowChanged` Event then go on there. the code is

```
private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(s,e)
{
   textEdit1.Text=gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("fieldName1").ToString();
   textEdit2.Text=gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("fieldName2").ToString(); 
   .
   .
   .
}
```